# Xcode 8.3 crashes when I try to build project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, xcode8

### Send to Apple reports information for details

```
Process: Xcode [31577]
Path: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier: com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version: 8.3 (12169)
Build Info: IDEFrameworks-12169000000000000~2
App Item ID: 497799835
App External ID: 821487965
Code Type: X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process: ??? [1]
Responsible: Xcode [31577]
User ID: 501

Date/Time: 2017-03-29 18:48:35.451 +0800
OS Version: Mac OS X 10.12.4 (16E195)
Report Version: 12
Anonymous UUID: 564BD29A-8710-A81C-C15D-B939D5755107


Time Awake Since Boot: 31000 seconds
System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread: 7 Dispatch queue: shared-compile-command-queue :: NSOperation 0x7fd5420c3cf0 (QOS: DEFAULT)

Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note: EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 8E162
ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-12169/IDEFoundation/Diagnostic/IDEDiagnosticActivityLogMessage.m:298
Details: (fixItString) should not be nil.
Object: <IDEDiagnosticFixItItem: 0x7fd53f133fa0>
Method: initWithFixItString:replacementLocation:
Thread: <NSThread: 0x7fd53d8d8030>{number = 18, name = (null)}
Hints:  

Backtrace:
```

> -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
>   _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
>   _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)

Comment: i think, your concern is this :    Details: (fixItString) should not be nil.
Object: <IDEDiagnosticFixItItem: 0x7fd53f133fa0>
Method: initWithFixItString:replacementLocation. Something is setting nil at run time. check it out

Comment: I found a place, but I don't know what the reason, the certificate which I also try to replace lead, or no problem

Comment: File a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com with the full crash and any reproduction steps you can provide.